# print sum (x) - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

could someone please help me with this. I always get an error with this code, but dont know whats wrong?

```
x= 1523

while x <= 10503:
    x=x+2
    print sum(x)
```

edit. sorry for being unclear. yes, i want to get the sum of all the numbers  from 1523 to 10503 (including) (interval of 2).

Comment: It might be beneficial for you if you explained what exactly you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 6):

The pythonic solution is:

```
print(sum(range(1523, 10504, 2)))
```

(Using a while loop to build a list containing a range of integers is a bit silly when there's a builtin that does it more efficiently.)

Comment: print(sum(range(1523, 10503, 2))) gives 26993880, but the other two solutions 27014888. why do you think is that?

Comment: You want 10504 for the second argument, since it needs to be higher than the last number in your range. phihag's solution will add 10505 at the end, and Pulimon's omits 1523.

Answer (score 5):

Why use a loop?

```
>>> ((10503-1523+2)//2  * (1523 + 10503))//2
27004383
```

This is just an extension of the old question "What's the sum of all integers from 1 to 100?" which is

```
50*101 (1+100 + 2+99 + 3+98 + ... 50+51)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that sum() only works with iterable types, such as tuples, lists, or similar.

And you are applaying sum to an integer, so that's not gona work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
x = 1523
x_list = []
while x <= 10503:
    x=x+2
    x_list.append(x)
print(sum(x_list))
```

I am assuming you want to get the sum of all numbers in an arithmetic progression whose first element is 1523, last element is 10503 and whose common difference is 2. It wasn't clear from your question

Comment: in case you are using python 2.x the last statement would be print sum(x_list) i.e. without the brackets

Comment: If you've imported `print_function` from [`__future__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html), the behavior is the same as in Python 3. If you have not imported it (and are consequently using the print `statement`), the parentheses are harmless, because they just group the value `sum(x_list)`. So there's absolutely no reason to omit the parentheses in 2.x.

Comment: Oh I have worked only in python 3.x till now. Thanks for the info.

Comment: i guess it needs to be x_list = [1523], because otherwise it will start at 1525.